# Access to array of input filenames (or other way to output CSV header only once)

Tags: csv, jq

I run jq with multiple identically-structured json files as input, to output a single CSV stream, with a jq script ending like:

```
| (map(keys) | add | unique) as $cols
| map(. as $row | $cols | map($row[.])) as $rows
| if (input_filename == "first-file.json" then $cols, $rows[] else $rows[] end
| @csv
```

where that third line is to avoid repeating the CSV header for each JSON file. It's an ugly hack because it hardcodes the first input filename. I'd like to instead use `input_filenames[0]` but there is no such global property — or am I missing it? Or is there some other neater way to avoid repeating the header row in the output CSV?

Comment: Could you share a minimal example of couple such JSON files?

Comment: file1.json: [{"foo": 1, "bar": 2},{"foo": 3, "bar": 4}]
file2.json: [{"foo": 5, "bar": 6}]
Invoke as:
jq -r -f script.jq file*.json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This response only addresses the issue of finding a:

> way to output CSV header only once

One way is to use `input` to handle the very first JSON entity, and then use `inputs` to handle the rest, all with jq's -n command-line option.

```
input
| . as $in
| (map(keys_unsorted) | add | unique) as $cols
| $cols,
  (($in, inputs) | map(. as $row | $cols | map($row[.])))
```

Note also the use of `keys_unsorted` here.

Comment: Thanks, this is quite close but yields: 
[
  "bar",
  "foo"
]
[
  [
    2,
    1
  ],
  [
    4,
    3
  ]
]
[
  [
    6,
    5
  ]
]
and the nesting borks @csv with the error "array ([2,1]) is not valid in a csv row" so not _quite_ there yet :)